# Calculate download speeds/packet loss /jitter /latency to servers on all the continents values (Android)

Tags: android, network-programming, video-streaming, rtsp, packet

I need to **calculate** the following:

- upload,
- download speed
- packet loss
- jitter
- latency to servers on all the continents
- locally and details about mobile carriers

Could someone please tell me what is the best way to track these things?

I need **accuracy** to be **high**.

Comment: Did you ever found a code to calculate jitter? (in any language!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please find the code to get latency.and mark it as solution if it solve your problem ,so that it helps the other to find the answer.

```
public String getLatency()
         {
            String latency ="";
                    String ip = "ip address of the server";
                    String pingCmd = "ping -c 25 " + ip;
                    try {
                        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        String latencyResult = null;
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            latencyResult = inputLine;
                        }
                        String[] keyValue = latencyResult.split("=");
                        String[] value = keyValue[1].split("/");
                        latency = value[1];                  
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                      LogWrite.d(TAG, "Exception..."+e);
                    }
            return latency ;                    
             }`
```

Comment: thanks i'll check. do you have any ideas regarding download speed,packet loss,locally and details about mobile carriers

Comment: In the above code, i just fetch latency ,but  it also provide you packet loss. just pick the last 2 to 3 lines of the while loop  and out of these lines one look like "25 packets transmitted, 22 received, 12% packet loss, time 24099ms" in the form of String just spit this string and get  the percentage of packet loss. mark this as solution if it solve your problem.

Comment: could you please explain further more. do you have any idea how to get
jitter correctly ?

Comment: I donot know  what is jitter. can you explain what do you want in this case.

Comment: In computer networking, packet delay variation (PDV) is the difference in end-to-end one-way delay between selected packets in a flow with any lost packets being ignored.The effect is sometimes referred to as jitter. could you have any ideas please ?

Comment: are u sure that your variable "latency" contains the latency value. Is it not the turn around time?

Comment: How can i get jitter and trace route ?

Comment: @VenushkaT Any solution you identified..? I need exactly what you asked for. Any lead will be helpful.